# how to render your own object instance reactively? (not a cursor obj)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to build something that should be a reasonably obvious code pattern in meteor, but feel like I must be doin' it wrong since reactivity is biting me in the foot.

I want to create my own Object instance and then pass that to the template to render. As the object internal state changes the template should update reacti-magically.

So for example the player enters a page, I want to create just one instance of this object. It's not a mongo find or a cursor but my own class.

So ideally I would create the object in something like an onRun() event in the router, and then pass that object to the data to render.

The below allows me to get the object, but not have the template update when it's internal state changes.

If I put the object into the Session, I get:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded ejson.js?
```

By sticking it into the @params of the router I can pass it from onRun to data, but this seems like a hack.

Is there another better way to create your own type of object and then pass it into a template to render reactively? Or do I need to delve into Deps.autorun() and setting up own Deps tracking for such a simple thing to work?

```
  @route 'magnets',
    path: '/magnets/lesson/:lessonCname/:subTopic?'
    waitOn: ->
      Meteor.subscribe('MagnetsQuery', {lessonCname: @params.lessonCname}, {} )

    onBeforeAction: ->
      console.log("onRun")
      if @ready()
        if @params.deck
          console.log('already had a deck')
        else
          deck = new DialogDeck(@params.lessonCname)
          Template.magnets.deck = deck
          console.log('created deck', deck)
          @params.deck = deck

    data: ->
      obj = {
        deck: @params.deck
        lessonCname: @params.lessonCname
        subTopic: @params.subTopic
      }
      console.log('data', obj)
      return obj
```

Comment: What changes the internal state of your object?

Comment: I have some buttons on the page that call methods on it. even changing a simple property of the object from the console doesn't update. I guess i may have to dig into Deps, or just create a simple mongo cursor to back end it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can incorporate a [Deps.Dependency](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency) into `DialogDeck` to make it a reactive data source. There is an excellent tutorial on how to do this [here](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-build-a-reactive-data-source).

Once you've done that, create `deck` in the template [created](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_created) function. Unlike the `onBeforeAction` iron-router hook, this is not reactive, so `deck` will only be created once.

Here is a simple example using a single `Dependency` for the entire `DialogDeck` object.

```
function DialogDeck (lessonCname) {
  this.lessonCname = lessonCname;
  this.dep = new Deps.Dependency;
};

var deck;

Template.magnets.created = function () {
  deck = new DialogDeck(this.data.lessonCname);
};

Template.magnets.deck = function () {
  deck.dep.depend();
  return deck;
};

Template.magnets.events({
  'click button': function () {
    deck.lessonCname = 'something different';
    deck.changed();
  }
});
```

Of course, you can use more dependencies to achieve greater granularity in rendering the template.

Comment: Isn't it better to use the created callback rather than the rendered callback in this case? So the helper won't be called twice.